# UI Local Notification - Background Reschedule

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8, uilocalnotification

I'm learning to develop application for ios with swift, and I'm one doubts, already googled and i not found.

I'm creating a to-do list app, and was wondering if there is a way to reschedule a notification when it appears to the user

For example the user registers a task every two hours, then the notification appears to the user and reagendo the new notification

Can anyone help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it in background if your app is suspended. But UILocalNotification supports recurrent notifications.
All you have to do is to declare the recurring interval: `notif.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;`

You can find [more details here](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/09/13/repeating-an-ios-local-notification.html).

Note that you can't set custom intervals. You must use the default ones [provided by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/repeatInterval).

Comment: So I can not escape from loop to create notifications.

As in my example for a task every 2 hours, 12 create notifications with  notif.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;

Or 4 notifications with notif.repeatInterval = NSHourCalendarUnit; for user case select a task every 15 min

Right?

What can I do if the user exceeds the 64 notifications permitted?