# iOS How can I POST http request in schedule?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cron, afnetworking, uilocalnotification

I am writing an app that the users can schedule an HTTP request. UILocalNotification can fire notifications on schedule but it seems like cannot call a method. It there any way for me to call a method or post the HTTP request in a scheduled time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this a while ago, so it may have changed, but you have Background Notifications that allow you to send an HTTP request, however you cannot say an exact time in which the request should occur. It's done by the systems usage. 
I think this answers it quite well:
[UI Local Notification - Background Reschedule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30737728/ui-local-notification-background-reschedule)

**Update**
I think specific to your question you want to look at background fetch:
https://www.objc.io/issues/5-ios7/multitasking/

Comment: It seems like not the thing that I want. I want to call a method on specific time that I selected.